# Click Radio button from Win32 SendMessage

Tags: c#, click, radio-button, dllimport

In a C# WPF application I am attempting to click a radio button on the uninstall screen for a click once application.

There are 2 radio buttons

- "Restore the application to its previous state." (this one is checked
  by default)
- "Remove the application from this computer." (this is the
  one I want to be checked).

Using some Win32 API’s I find the handle to the radio button and then click it. Unfortunately nothing happens (the radio button does not get checked).  On a side note there is an Ok button on that window I have successfully clicked.

I have used Spy++ to check what messages get passed when I manually click the radio button and compared them to the messages I am sending through code (both are the same).

Spy++ Messages I send from code

```
<00001> 000D1136 S BM_SETCHECK fCheck:BST_CHECKED
<00002> 000D1136 R BM_SETCHECK
```

Spy++ messages sent when I click the radio button using mouse

```
<00099> 000D1136 S BM_SETCHECK fCheck:BST_CHECKED
<00100> 000D1136 R BM_SETCHECK
```

Below is a snippet of the code I’m using to click the radio button.

```
[DllImport("User32.Dll")]
private static extern IntPtr SendMessage(IntPtr hWnd, uint Msg, int wParam, IntPtr lParam);

private const int BST_CHECKED = 0x0001;
private const int BM_SETCHECK = 0x00F1;


public static void DoRadioButtonClick(IntPtr RadioButtonHandle)
{
    SendMessage(RadioButtonHandle, BM_SETCHECK, BST_CHECKED, IntPtr.Zero);
}
```

Comment: Few questions: with which technology application you want to _automate_ is built with? For example a WinForms app won't react to BM_SETCHECK  for radio buttons. 2nd point: I guess you don't _click_ OK button using BM_SETCHECK. 3rd point: you can also simulate keyboard using SendKeys()...

Comment: I’m using a WPF application, however I’m unsure if the window with the radio button on is a WPF application (that’s part of click once). The ok button is clicked using SendMessage(ButtonHandle, BM_CLICK, IntPtr.Zero, IntPtr.Zero). Not sure how I would go about using the SendKeys as the radio button does not have focus.

Comment: Use UI Automation to automate UI

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved the problem by sending a mouse down event to the radio button.

```
SendMessage(RadioButtonHandle, 513, 0x00000001, 0x000d0026);
```

513 = MouseDown message
Not sure about the other two values.

Comment: The other two values aren't required. You can use 
SendMessage(RadioButtonHandle, 513, IntPtr.Zero, IntPtr.Zero);